# How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android 2023

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to disable reCaptcha in firebase phone-auth (OTP) android 2023

Please help.

To remove Firebase reCaptcha Verification phone auth.
Safety Net has been deprecated, I have tried using playIntegrity, but firebase always asks for reCaptcha on my android device.
I have added the sha1, and sha256 keys. No problem there.

Out of ideas now. My App Check Firebase uses playIntegrity, and safety net is disabled after 31st Jan.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disable it also from Google [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) for your projects, then See **APIs & Services** >  **Enabled APIs & services**, then under the library list, search for **Android Device Verification** and Disable it.

Here is how it looks in one of my projects:

[image]

Comment: After searching **Android Device Verification** in google cloud console it will redirect to **Google Play Integrity API**. After enable google play integrity still recaptcha is showing after submit the phone number to the firebase

Comment: @RSumanRadhakrishnan have you found the solution I got the same problem

Comment: No, I am also still searching for the solution. @samadshukr

Comment: You got any solution yet?